# Need advice on DynamoDB schema

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I've been trying to wrap my head around dynamoDB for a few days now and I kind of still feel lost even after poring through the docs and articles online.

Say if I have a table for storing books by users, should my primary key be userId and sort key be bookId? Why is userId being the primary key recommended as opposed to bookId?

And if each book needs to contain multiple attachmentUrls, should I worry if the attachmentUrls go over the limit? If it does, how can that be handled?

And say if I need to store another attribute to the user, say a googleRefreshToken, should I be using an LSI?
Because in this instance, I don't require a bookId, by just creating an item without the bookId, it would throw an error since userId and bookId were a part of the composite. 
What would be the best way to design such a schema, if going by best practices, I should only have 1 table?

Comment: Your schema and use of secondary indexes should be dictated by your access patterns. When you have a book, how is your application/user looking up the book? By title, author, etc? It might be where you use the GSI overloading. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-gsi-overloading.html While you might be duplicating data because the data is denormalized, that is just a trade-off and may be ok because the gains you get in low latency, velocity of data, scale, etc. that you can achieve with DynamoDB. I need more information on your access patterns.

Comment: Hi Kirk. Each user can only access their own books. The application's core functionality would be to allow a user to login, and create books comprising of only images. I suppose up to this point it's straightforward. But say the user intends to get images from the Google drive(meaning the application needs to store the user's Google refresh token server-side to download the images), this is where I'm kind of lost on how the schema should be designed.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I was not talking security access. I mean how is your app letting users look up their books? Is it a drop down on author, title, ISBN, or something else? For the google refresh token, when the app needs that, does it need other data as well? More than likely I would store it as a separate object from the other data. Only get the data you need exactly when you need it.

Comment: Ah I see. Basically they access their profile page, and their books will load as a list. On this profile page, it's likely only the first image of each book will be fetched(as a thumbnail to display). Only after a user clicks onto 1 book, will that single book's images load.

Comment: For the refresh token, yes other data is needed but they don't need to be stored. On the client-side, they are authenticated by google oauth. An auth code is received then sent to the backend for the application to authenticate themselves on behalf of the user. This is when a refresh token is received. And the reason why this needs to be stored is because Google will not send a refresh token on subsequent authentications.